# changing remote url for BitBucket in Microsoft GIT provider

Tags: visual-studio-2013, bitbucket

I'm using BitBucket with Microsoft GIT Provider into Visual Studio 2013. 
I have inserted once the remote URL where to publish, but now when the repository name  has been changed in BitBucket, also the remote URL has been changed and I need to modify it into VisualStudio to reference the new repository name.

I'm not able to modify the remote URL in VisualStudio. Nowhere I can found an option to change it. I'm not able to use bash commands. Is there a way to achieve a remote repository URL change through Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution! 
There is a **hidden** folder named **.git** in your project root folder. Into this folder there is file called **config**. You can open it with any text editor, such as notepad++ and edit the line which specifies the remote URL for this repository.

The setting I needed was **url** under the **[remote "origin"]** section. 
The file looks like:

```
[core]
bare = false
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = false
symlinks = false
ignorecase = true
logallrefupdates = true
[diff]
tool = vsdiffmerge
[difftool]
prompt = true
[difftool "vsdiffmerge"]
cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common7\\IDE\\vsdiffmerge.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" //t
keepbackup = false
trustexistcode = true
[merge]
tool = vsdiffmerge
[mergetool]
prompt = true
[mergetool "vsdiffmerge"]
cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common7\\IDE\\vsdiffmerge.exe\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\" //m
keepbackup = false
trustexistcode = true

[remote "origin"]
url = https://username@bitbucket.org/user/repoName.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

[branch "master"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
```